# tcgetattr and tcsetattr in job contol seems to break termcaps

Tags: c, jobs, termcap

**tcgetattr and tcsetattr in job contol**

Hello everyone. 
I'm currently recreating a shell in C, which include jobcontrol.

I'm now recoding the fg built-in.

According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Data-Structures.html#Data-Structures) and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Foreground-and-Background.html#Foreground-and-Background) documentation, it seems they save the termios in the job structure when creating new job, then restauring it with `tcsetattr`.

I am trying to do (almost) the same.
here is my code:

When I am creating a new job in my linked list:

```
static t_jobs_lst   *new(void)
{
    t_jobs_lst *job;

    if (!(job = (t_jobs_lst *)malloc(sizeof(t_jobs_lst))))
        return (NULL);
    job->command = NULL;
    job->job_number = g_shell.jobs.index++;
    job->pid = 0;
    job->childs = NULL;
    job->current = '+';
    job->state = "Running";
    tcgetattr(STDERR_FILENO, &job->tmodes);
    job->prev = NULL;
    job->next = NULL;
    jobs_insert(job);
    return (job);
}
```

And when i try to set it in foreground:

```
int     change_grp(t_shell *shell, int converted, int cont)
{
    t_jobs_lst  *searched;
    int         wpid;
    int         status;

    signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
    searched = job_search(shell, converted);
    if (tcsetpgrp(STDERR_FILENO, searched->pid) < 0)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    ft_printf("%s\n", searched->command);
    /* Send the job a continue signal, if necessary.  */
    if (cont)
    {
        tcsetattr(STDERR_FILENO, TCSADRAIN, &searched->tmodes); //causing bug in termcaps when uncommented
        if (kill(-searched->pid, SIGCONT) < 0)
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    wpid = 0;
    status = 0;
    while (!wpid)
    {
        pause();
        wpid = waitpid(searched->pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    }
    if (tcsetpgrp(0, shell->pid) < 0)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    /* Restore the shell's terminal modes.  */
    tcgetattr (STDERR_FILENO, &searched->tmodes);
    tcsetattr (STDERR_FILENO, TCSADRAIN, &shell->prev_term);
    job_delete(shell, searched->pid);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My question is: when `tcsetattr(STDERR_FILENO, TCSADRAIN, &searched->tmodes); //causing bug in termcaps when uncommented` is uncommented, it seems to break my termcaps, as you can see in the following picture.

If this line is commented, I cannot type anything, only hit CTRL-C will give me the hand back on the shell.

I should be able to type AND to hit CTRL-C when i want to stop it, as said in the first link.

> If the process group is launched as a background job, the shell should remain in the foreground itself and continue to read commands from the terminal.

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: So compare the struct termios and see what's different

Comment: Hey ! Nothing is different, because if i try to restaure originals termcaps (shell->prev_terms), it will also break it...

Comment: The code fragment isn't a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  By the way, "termcap" is irrelevant to the question.